# Theos for armv7 and arm64

Tags: objective-c, jailbreak, cydia, theos

I'm trying to get theos working on OSX Mavericks. I recently purchased an iPhone 5s and have since then jailbroken it. Now I am trying to get Theos working so I can start working on some tweaks again. I had it working on OSX Lion and for IOS 5 and 6. I have a very simple program which should display a UIAlert when an application launches. The problem is, when i run the make command in an attempt to compile my code i get this error:

```
Making all for tweak test...
 Preprocessing Tweak.xm...
 Compiling Tweak.xm...
 Linking tweak test...
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIAlertView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Tweak.xm.b0410391.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [obj/test.dylib.1cc22e7c.unsigned] Error 1
make[1]: *** [internal-library-all_] Error 2
make: *** [test.all.tweak.variables] Error 2
Williams-MacBook-Pro-2:test williamfsmillie$
```

Here is my code for Tweak.xm:

```
%hook SBApplicationIcon

-(void)launch{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"TEST" message:@"message...." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    %orig;
}

%end
```

And my makefile:

```
export SDKVERSION=7.0

include theos/makefiles/common.mk

TWEAK_NAME = test
test_FILES = Tweak.xm
ARCHS = armv7 arm64
test_FRAMEWORKS = UIKit

include $(THEOS_MAKE_PATH)/tweak.mk

after-install::
    install.exec "killall -9 SpringBoard"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Theos is an abbreviation of Theodores, isn't it?  Who know!?

Answer (score 7):

It's an old question, but still I figured I should answer it for people who have the same question. You need to call `objc_getClass` for it to work, like this:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[objc_getClass("UIAlertView") alloc] initWithTitle:@"TEST" message:@"message...." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

Note that this is not required on the left hand side of the assignment.

Comment: You could also use `%c(UIAlertView)` instead of `objc_getClass("UIAlertView")`

Answer (score 4):

Edit your makefile and insert the following at the top:

```
export ARCHS = armv7 armv7s arm64
export TARGET = iphone:clang:7.0:7.0
```

Also, link the `Foundation` framework with your tweak.

Comment: Hmm... compiles fine but the UIAlert doesn't appear. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

To fix the alert issue, you must include UIKit/UIKit.h (Sorry, I can't comment)

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the UIKit framework in your **Makefile** by adding  **XXX_FRAMEWORKS = UIKit** where XXX is your project name

Answer (score 1):

If you're using iOS 7, you have to hook the correct method: try `-(void)launchFromLocation:(int)location`.

Because it uses a parameter, your code should look like this:

```
-(void)launchFromLocation:(int)location {
    // your stuff
    %orig(location);
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to down vote, but SO will not permit to change my vote. Dumb.

Comment: Upvoted to cancel out @alexgray's accidental downvote.

Answer (score 0):

I would say update your Headers.
Download new set from
[rpetrich](https://github.com/rpetrich/iphoneheaders)